# advantages of using OData connector over Custom apex connector

Tags: externalobjects, odata

so I have connected an external data source to salesforce using custom apex connector, 
I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of doing the same with odata connector.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that you don't have to write code. The disadvantage is that you cannot support features that are not supported by the system library. There might also be a trivial difference in performance for using the OData Connector, but it's not enough of a difference to make it a major deciding factor.

Comment: Another advantage of OData is that this applies a defined industry standard so external systems may well be able to invoke operations on the API without any code on their side too.

Comment: @sfdcfox - so true; I had nothing but frustration with OData Connector due to limitations on features we needed

Comment: so I found one more, OData by default performs Query over URI so all the queries are performed on server side first, then result set is sent back to salesforce.

Comment: while with custom apex connector, by default everytime you perform a query all the data is fetched then query is performed on salesforce side. It can be changed to operate like Odata by a simple apex Code though.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/366781/65083) where my SAP B1 external system is compliant with OData, except there's a unique endpoint to get the cookie auth going - this is preventing me from using the built-in OData connector