# Salesforce Connect OData v4 needs a cookie from /Login endpoint before talking to data endpoints

Tags: namedcredentials, odata, salesforce-connect

Here's a rundown of my Salesforce Connect setup:

**FIRST** I was able to set up a `Named Credential`, using password authentication

- API Name: MyAPI
- URL: https://myapi:50000/b1/v2

**SECOND** I then created an `External Data Source` that leverages the above:

- URL: `callout:MyAPI`
- Format: `JSON`
- Server Driven Pagination: `checked`

Salesforce successfully presents to me a `Validate and Sync` screen (a listing of my external system entities) - I'm imagining in order to render the choices on the screen, Salesforce must have somehow called out the the `/$metadata` endpoint, parsed the XML response (from this screen SF makes `External Object` definitions for whichever items I check-marked)

**THIRD** I can see the `external objects` that Salesforce creates. These look fully fleshed out with lots of fields defined, so I'm feeling good.

**FOURTH** I create a new `Tab` for one of my custom objects (i.e. External Objects) so I select my new `Orders` external object

**FIFTH** When I navigate to my new custom tab, choose to 'View all', it spins and spins eventually errors out

When I do some apex debugging, I can see that whatever SF apex logic is doing.. it tries to interact with my org, but it is NOT first going to my `/Login` endpoint. My external system, when I read it's docs, requires that you first get 'cookied' by visiting the `/Login` endpoint with a `POST` operation - from there it will respond with a `Set-cookie` header

I know how to make all this work with hand-rolled APEX code, but shouldn't this work with SF Connect? Or must I use a [Custom Adapter for Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.apex_adapter_about.htm&type=5)?

### To reiterate my problem, the debug logs show

- attempt authenticate at: GET https://myapi:50000/b1/v2
- then it correctly calls: GET https://myapi:50000/b1/v2/Orders?$count=true

### But I need it to...

- attempt authenticate at:  POST https://myapi:50000/b1/v2/Login
- and use cookied calls at: GET https://myapi:50000/b1/v2/Orders?$count=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I found a Andy Chiarelli's [Reverse Proxy example](https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/) in the form of dotnet WebAPI which I find familar to work with
2. I pulled it down [from his github](https://github.com/andychiare/netcore2-reverse-proxy) and customized it to do the work of hiding my undesirable API complexity
3. I now have a successful implementation which detects the `GET` request from Salesforce (which, if responding to the credential challenge, would also have a Basic Auth header), and transforms it into a POST request to /Login endpoint

   - Note in this screenshot, there is no “/Login” path shown in the initial request (address bar)
   - Nevertheless we see it delivered the cookie'd JSON response as if I had
     [image: screenshot of my proxy in action]